# Integral over vector field

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, vector-analysis

Can someone help me with this one:

Let $X$ be a vector field on $R^{3}$ such that $X(x)=x$, for each $x\in S^{2}$. Calculate

$$\int\limits_{\overline{B^3(1)}} \left(\frac{\partial X_1}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial X_2}{\partial x_2} + \frac{\partial X_2}{\partial x_2}\right) \, dx_1 \, dx_2 \, dx_3$$

where $\overline{B^3(1)}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid \|x\| \leq 1\}$

Comment: Is $x$ a vector here?

Answer (score 1):

This calls for the Divergence Theorem (a classical consequence of Stokes). Setting as usual
$\operatorname{div}(X)=\sum_i\frac{\partial X_i}{\partial x_i}$ we have
$$
\int_D \operatorname{div}(X)=\int_S\langle X,\nu\rangle,
$$
where $D$ is the closed ball, $S$ its boundary the sphere, and $\nu(x)=x$ the normal field to the boundary. In the given case:
$$
\int_D\operatorname{div}(X)=\int_S x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=\int_S 1=\operatorname{surface area}(S)=4\pi.
$$

Comment: No divergence theorem needed here.

Comment: How to avoid some kind of reduction to the boundary?

Comment: you only take a derivative when you go from the boundary to the volume.  The integral is over a volume.

Comment: The integral is over a volume, but we don't know the form over the volume, we only know it on the boundary, hence you need to reduce the volume integral to a surface one. To do that, you don't take a derivative, but a primitive (Stokes). The div is not a choice: it's in the problem (and can be solved because it is there).

Comment: @Paul: no further comment!?